# Error Inserting Jquery POST to Controller / SQL Database

Tags: jquery, sql, controller

I'm trying to insert data from MVC5 application view from a jquery POST to controller into sql database. I'm getting an error because there was a conflict with "FOREIGN KEY Property". I think my problem is, that jquery POST is returning the wrong ID for Foreign Key Entry.

View code

```
$("#BtnSave").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = JSON.stringify({
                KundeId: document.getElementById("Kunde").value, //$('#Kunde option:selected').attr('id'), //$("#Kunde").children(":selected").attr("id"),
                RechnungsNummer: $("#Code").val(),
                RechnungsDatum: $("#Datum").val(),
    });
});

function saveOrder(data) {
    return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Rechnung/Create",
            data: data
    });
}
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Rechnung rechnung)
{
    var artikel = _rechnungService.Artikellistes(HttpContext);

    var rechnungmodel = new Rechnung
            {
                Rechnungsnummer = rechnung.Rechnungsnummer,
                Rechnungsdatum = rechnung.Rechnungsdatum, //DateTime.Parse(rechnung.Rechnungsdatum.ToString("d")),

                Faelligkeit = DateTime.Now,//rechnung.Faelligkeit, //DateTime.Parse(rechnung.Faelligkeit.ToString("d")),
                KundeId = rechnung.KundeId
            };

    db.Rechnungs.Add(rechnungmodel);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try using the network tab in chrome developer tools to see the data sent in your ajax request to check the id

Comment: In network tab "KundeId" shows up with value "undefined". I've got a select list where you can select the customer (Kunde).  The function for lookup select list value is: So how can I get the Id Value?             $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                url: "/Rechnung/GetKunde",
                datatype: "Json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        $('#Kunde').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.Nachname + " " + value.Vorname + '</option>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting KundeId using jQuery:

```
$("#BtnSave").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        KundeId: $("#Kunde").val(),
        RechnungsNummer: $("#Code").val(),
        RechnungsDatum: $("#Datum").val()
    });
});
```

You may also try:

```
$('#Kunde').find(":selected").text();
```

**EDIT**

You can get the id using the attr :

```
 $('#Kunde').find(":selected").attr('value');
```

Comment: Nearly there... When I use $('#Kunde').find(":selected").text(); it returns the selected value in Select List. I need to have the Id Number which belongs to the selected value for inserting value into database.

Comment: When I use your edited value in chrome development network tab the Id value is not listed. If I'm using ...(":selected").val("id") it returns a zero... Really difficult, cause the jquery lookup (GET) for Dropdown lists shows me all values from the datatable

Comment: When I manually set KundeId in controller to 1 it's working perfectly. So the error definetly caused by jquery